# How get key signal and not deleting it in wxTextCtrl

Tags: wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

In initialize functions on my widgets i have:

```
Connect(wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER, wxCommandEventHandler(MyTextCtrl::EnterClick));
```

next I have

```
void MyTextCtrl::EnterClick(wxCommandEvent &event)
{ wxPrintf(wxT("enter\n"));}
```

trouble is with signal. the string is putting to console but on editor not working enter. How using specyfic key and no deleting it signal?

I would using key (making some procedure) but i would normal using it deeper

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
event.Skip();
```

on the end of functions, nothing more